# ¿Cómo extraigo un vector de valores únicos de una matriz?

Tags: r, nlp

Tengo una matriz cuyas columnas son la separación de diferentes frases en palabras independientes. Ejemplo:

| Frase | Palabra_1 | Palabra_2 | Palabra_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Texto de ejemplo | Texto | de | ejemplo |
| Frase de ejemplo | Frase | de | ejemplo |
| Palabra separada | Palabra | separada | NA |
| Gracias de antemano | Gracias | de | antemano |

Necesito extraer un vector a modo de diccionario en el que se encuentren los valores únicos de estas palabras separadas. Aplicado al ejemplo, el resultado que necesito es el siguiente:

| Diccionario |
| --- |
| antemano |
| de |
| ejemplo |
| frase |
| gracias |
| palabra |
| separada |
| texto |

Tengan en cuenta que el código debe omitir los NA, pues todas las frases no tienen la misma longitud.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Saludos,
J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para agregar una columna de conteo, puedes agregar al final del código de la respuesta anterior lo siguiente:

```
df <- dataframe %>% 
        gather(key = nombre_columna, value = Diccionario, -Frase) %>% 
        filter(!is.na(Diccionario)) %>% 
        select(Diccionario) %>% 
        mutate(Diccionario = stringr::str_to_lower(Diccionario)) %>% 
        unique() %>% 
        group_by(Diccionario) %>% # Agrupa las palabras en base a una 
                                    condición
        summarize(n = n()) %>%    # Realiza la suma del conteo de palabras
        arrange(desc(n))          # Ordena el conteo de palabras de mayor a 
                                    menor
```

Si lo comparas con la respuesta anterior he eliminado la función `unique`, para que se cuenten las palabras repetidas, de lo contrario, todas las palabras tendrán como valor de conteo 1.

**OUTPUT**

```
 Diccionario     n
  <chr>       <int>
1 de              3
2 ejemplo         2
3 antemano        1
4 frase           1
5 gracias         1
6 palabra         1
7 separada        1
8 texto           1
```

Por otro lado, para eliminar las palabras que aparezcan menos de n veces. Acá está un ejemplo que elimina aquellas palabras cuyo conteo es menor a 2.

```
df %>% 
  filter(n >= 2) # Para elegir otro valor sólo debes cambiar el valor de la 
                   función
```

**OUTPUT**

```
  Diccionario     n
  <chr>       <int>
1 de              3
2 ejemplo         2
```

Comment: Hola Isaac, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Hay un detalle en el que creo que me he explicado mal. Lo último que necesito con el filtro es que una vez seleccionadas las palabras que aparecen menos de n veces, borrarla del dataframe en el que tengo separada la frase por columnas.

Ej.: Si la palabra "Ejemplo" aparece menos de n veces, en el dataframe quiero que donde aparece esa palabra ponga NA, eliminándola así por completo del dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa es utilizar las librerías `dplyr`, `stringr` y `tidyr`, a través del siguiente código:

```
dataframe %>% 
  gather(key = nombre_columna, value = Diccionario, -Frase) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Diccionario)) %>% 
  select(Diccionario) %>% 
  mutate(Diccionario = stringr::str_to_lower(Diccionario)) %>% 
  unique()
```

Vi que el output deseado contiene todas las palabras en minúscula, por lo que puedes utilizar `stringr::str_to_lower` para estandarizar las palabras.

**Output**

```
   Diccionario
1       texto
2       frase
3     palabra
4     gracias
5          de
6    separada
7     ejemplo
8    antemano
```

Comment: Hola Isaac, tu respuesta fue muy útil, muchas gracias. Tengo una cuestión... ¿Cómo puedo hacer para añadir una columna de "conteo" de apariciones de esa palabra? Además, me gustaría saber cómo eliminar totalmente del dataframe las palabras que aparezcan menos de n veces. Mil gracias de antemano. 
J.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres que el dataframe se guarde como un objeto independiente puedes guardarlo asignandolo a una nueva variable llamada `nuevo_dataframe`:

```
nuevo_dataframe <- dataframe %>% 
  gather(key = nombre_columna, value = Diccionario, -Frase) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Diccionario)) %>% 
  select(Diccionario) %>% 
  mutate(Diccionario = stringr::str_to_lower(Diccionario)) %>% 
  unique()
```

En el caso del parametro key en la función gather, se refiere a al nombre de la columna donde se registra el nombre de las columnas que estás agrupando. En el caso del código anterior no lo puedes ver, ya que el dataframe es modificado hasta obtener el resultado desesado, pero si quieres ver el resultado, puedes revisarlo corriendo esta parte del código:

```
dataframe %>% 
  gather(key = nombre_columna, value = Diccionario, -Frase)

                 Frase nombre_columna Diccionario
1     Texto de ejemplo      Palabra_1       Texto
2     Frase de ejemplo      Palabra_1       Frase
3     Palabra separada      Palabra_1     Palabra
4  Gracias de antemano      Palabra_1     Gracias
5     Texto de ejemplo      Palabra_2          de
6     Frase de ejemplo      Palabra_2          de
7     Palabra separada      Palabra_2    separada
8  Gracias de antemano      Palabra_2          de
9     Texto de ejemplo      Palabra_3     ejemplo
10    Frase de ejemplo      Palabra_3     ejemplo
11    Palabra separada      Palabra_3        <NA>
12 Gracias de antemano      Palabra_3    antemano
```